# Change width of UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How would you change just the width of a UIImageView in objective-c? Currently I'm doing this:

```
imageview.frame = GCRectMake(x,y,width,height);
```

But when I change the width it seems to just change the position rather then change the size.

Answer (score 7):

try this:

```
CGRect frame = [imageView frame];
frame.size.width = newWidth;
[imageView setFrame:frame];
```